# How does update cycle behave for a React Component that conditionally renders JSX?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following scenario-

Here on each click of button, setState occurs which will initiate update cycle for class component Main. This will eventually cause the render function to execute. In each successive clicks, a new component gets rendered ( if prior to click its ComponentA then after the click it will be ComponentB and vice versa ) from parent component Main.

As per Reacts diffing algorithm, if the component returned from render is identical (===) to the component from the previous render, React recursively updates the subtree by diffing it with the new one. If they’re not equal, the previous subtree is unmounted completely.

My question is, does setState in this example actually lead to mount cycle for Main instead of update OR it causes update cycle for Main component but inside it, unmounting of ComponentA and mounting of ComponentB ( and vice versa as per the case of even or odd count) ??

Code for the case:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {ComponentA, ComponentB} from './componets' // just for namesake

class Main extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: 0};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Conditional rendering example in react</h1>
        {(this.state.count)%2 == 0 ? (<ComponentA/>) : (<ComponentB/>)}
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState((state)=>({count:state.count+1}))}}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the above code, when you update count, the ComponentA and ComponentB are the ones who will be mounted and unmounted as the state changes and not the Main component.

Also note that when ComponentA unmounts, all children rendered by ComponentA will also be unmounted, similar will be the case for ComponentB and for mounting

The diffing algorithm actually goes on tag by tag onto the leaf child nodes

Comment: Thanks Shubham. So that would mean that since its an update for Main, all its current state info will remain intact but the child component using that info would unmount and mount.??

Comment: Yes, the current state of Main will remain intact and only the states of ComponentA or ComponentB will reset when they mount depending on condition